# Packaging a PHP application

Tags: php, deployment, build, phar

I am trying to create a .phar file from my web application. Following the [php documentation's example](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.buildfromiterator.php) I tried the following for this purpose.

```
<?php
$srcRoot = __DIR__ . "/../app";
$buildRoot = __DIR__ . "/../build";
$p = new Phar("$buildRoot/build.phar", 0, 'build.phar');
$p->buildFromIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($srcRoot)
    ),
    $srcRoot
);
```

However I got the following error. I dont have any idea about the error. What is wrong with the code?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message
'Iterator RecursiveIteratorIterator returned a path "D:\site\app" that is
 not in the base directory "D:\site\app"'
in D:\site\tools\create-phar.php:7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source of the problem is that [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php) also lists the dot files - `.` and `..`.
When iterating over `/path/to/foo` it also lists `/path/to/foo/.` and `/path/to/foo/..` which goes to the parent directory - outside the base directory.

Thus you have to prevent the inclusion of the ".." files, which is most easily achieved with [`FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants.skip-dots) as second parameter to DirectoryIterator:

```
new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($srcRoot, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
```

Comment: I wonder why this is not mentioned in the example of the documentation. Does it ever work without that option?

Comment: Maybe default flags were changed in some PHP version. I've added a note to the manual yesterday.

Comment: The solution proposed by @cweiske is brilliant!  You can also insert FilterIterator if you need more exclusions.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

(@cweiske -- I just realized you beat me to it, I'll make sure to refresh the page next time, my sincerest apologies!)

You need just a slight edit to skip over the unix paths /. and /..:

```
<?php
$srcRoot = __DIR__ . "/../app";
$buildRoot = __DIR__ . "/../build";
$p = new Phar("$buildRoot/build.phar", 0, 'build.phar');
$p->buildFromIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($srcRoot, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
    ),
    $srcRoot
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Box](http://box-project.org/) makes it very easy to create PHAR archives from your source files. Basically you first add a configuration file and then you can create your PHAR file by simply invoking `box build` on the command line.

There is a [great blog post](http://moquet.net/blog/distributing-php-cli/) by Matthieu Moquet describing how he used Box to simplify the distribution of a PHP Cli application. Personally, I've also been using Box for a CLI application, however the official project description is not limited to CLI applications, but rather summarizes the Box project as:

> An application for building and managing Phars.

The Box project provides the PHAR build script and takes care of setting all paths correctly, so this might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks FaKell, I tried Box and it actually generate a PHAR file. However the files in phar archive seem not to able to include non-phar fies. Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you sure the error originates from the Box project? Have you ever successfully created a PHAR file of your project that is working? If not, then PHP is known to have issues with [realpath inside PHAR](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52769) files. How are you trying to include the files?

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by [@cweiske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282601/cweiske) is brilliant.  In some situations, however, you may need the ability to add more directory path exclusions.  Have a look at this example that excludes any references to the `.git` directory, using `FilterIterator`:

```
// create phar
$p = new Phar($pharFile, 0, $pharFile);

// produce iteration which excludes any references to values assigned to $excludes
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
);
$filter = new class($iterator) extends FilterIterator {
    public static $excludes = [];
    public function accept()
    {
        $item = $this->current();
        $actual   = 0;
        foreach (self::$excludes as $exclude) {
            $actual += (int) boolval(strpos($item->getPath(), $exclude));
        }
        return ($actual === 0);
    }
};
$filter::$excludes = ['.git'];

$p->buildFromIterator($filter, $path);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at php.ini file to check the value of phar.readonly field.
It must be 0 to create phar archive.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/phar.configuration.php#ini.phar.readonly